# Is fclose() necessary in read only file pointers?

Tags: c, file, pointers

I know it's good practice closing every file pointer that is opened, but I've been thinking that fclose() only actually does something when someone is working with files on write/all mode where the user actually needs to save the new content on the file.

But does having no fclose() actually affects read only pointers in any way? I've done some testing but I haven't gotten anything different from when I was using fclose().

Is there something else that I should be aware?

Comment: Opening a file consumes some user and kernel resources. If you open enough files without closing it will eventually cause a resource allocation failure. Don't do it.

Comment: All resources should be released.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Opened file pointers may leak without `fclose()` and they may prevent from opening more files when you do file operations many times.

This is a test code that do `fopen()` many times.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
        FILE* fp = fopen("test.txt", "r");
        int data;
        printf("%3d : ", i);
        if (fp != NULL) {
            if (fscanf(fp, "%d", &data) == 1) {
                printf("data = %d\n", data);
            } else {
                puts("read failed");
            }
            fclose(fp);
        } else {
            puts("fopen failed");
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

This code [successfully done 1000 operations](https://wandbox.org/permlink/1NYGGEvCTkpBPQV2) on Wandbox.

On the other hand, When I commented out the `fclose(fp);` line, [the operation began to fail after successful 251 operations](https://wandbox.org/permlink/K5kKdxVkdlmFW0ON).

Answer (score -1):

When working with files I open file with "w+" to create or overwrite existing file. And then when I want to write new entry to the file I open it again with "wa" write what you need using `fprintf` and then close it.